# Are Laravel 5.2 queries lazy loaded?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I am working with Laravel 5.2 and the eloquent models to interact with my database and I am wondering when the query is actually sent to the server?

I am developing a search/sort bar where need to build a query based on which values are presented. For example: ("" means no value selected)

Destination->Paris  Airport->""  Sort-> ""

So I am building my queries based on if else statements right now. Building many different queries based on which values are filled in. i.e. (Query for above values)

```
if(Destination != "" && Airport == "" && Sort == "")
Flight::where(['destination']=>Destination)->get();
```

So I have to do this 9 different times for each of the possible combinations with this approach. What I'm wondering is when is the query actually executed? It seems like it would be when you call ->get() method on the model? Is this how it works? If so I could do something like this, and it would make my life much easier. (psuedo code)

```
$query = Flight();
if(Destination != "")
    $query->where(['destination'=>Destination]
if(Airport != "") 
    $query->where(['airport'=>Airport])
etc...
```

Maybe a silly question, but having trouble with the googling.

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query will be executed when you call `get()`, `all()` or `first()` methods. If you want to see how many queries Laravel executed per each request and what exactly queries did it build, install debugbar.

Add this to `composer.json`:

```
"require-dev": {
    "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^2.2",
```

And run `composer update`.

Comment: thank you.  Simple question, straight forward response. Thanks for link to debugger as well.